# Is it possible to implement 5-click command? Or Long Press on Image

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
<Image HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="150"  Source="AppLogoWhite.png">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                      Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"
                      NumberOfTapsRequired="2" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
```

It works as expected. However when I change NumberOfTapsRequired from 2 to 5, it doesn't work any more. Is this behaviour expected? Is it possible to implement 5-click command?
Or Long Press on Image?

Answer (score 1):

I thought there was an issue, or maybe intended, behaviour on Android that didn't allow you to set a value higher than 2.

Of course one way to get around that is to implement a mechanism in your tapped event that counts for you.

In your code-behind add a counter: `private int _tapCounter = 0;`

And with each tap increment it:

```
private void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArguments EventArgs)
{
    _tapCounter++;

   if (_tapCounter == 5)
   {
       _tapCounter = 0;
       DoStuff();
   }
}
```

Of course a long press gesture is also an option but you would need to implement it yourself of use external libraries. For instance [MR.Gestures](http://www.mrgestures.com/)